# Difference between 2 given times in milliseconds in python

Tags: python, time, milliseconds

I have two times in the following format.
I want to find the time difference in milliseconds.
This is giving only seconds accuracy. 
How to make this work for milliseconds ?
Thanks. New to python.

```
import time
t1 = "2013-09-13 15:43:35,893"
t2 = "2013-09-13 15:43:45,147"
TIME_FORMAT2 = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,%f"
t11 = time.mktime(time.strptime(t1, TIME_FORMAT2))
t12 = time.mktime(time.strptime(t2, TIME_FORMAT2))
print t11-t12
```

Comment: How can this possibly work? There is no fractional seconds field in `struct_time`

Comment: What you need is the `datetime` module, not the `time` module.

Answer (score 6):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.strptime(t1, TIME_FORMAT2) - datetime.strptime(t2, TIME_FORMAT2)
datetime.timedelta(-1, 86390, 746000)
>>> _.total_seconds()
-9.254
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want milliseconds and dates in the same object, use a [datetime](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) object.  Unfortunately, there's no parser for date/time in the format you're given.  You can use a simple regular expression, though:

```
import time, datetime, re

dt_pat = re.compile(r"(\d+)\-(\d+)-(\d+)\s+(\d+):(\d+):(\d+),(\d+)")
def mstime( tstr ):
    m = dt_pat.match( tstr )
    if m==None: return m
    v = [int(s) for s in m.groups()]
    return datetime.datetime(*v)


t1 = "2013-09-13 15:43:35,893"
t2 = "2013-09-13 15:43:45,147"
dt1 = mstime( t1 )
dt2 = mstime( t2 )
diff = dt2-dt1
print diff.total_seconds()
```

Comment: There is one, the OP and gnibbler's answer use it. :)